# Trying to push a pair of array values into a another array randomly without duplicates javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, random, push

I'm trying to make an memory card game but this part is hard to figure out. I have an array with a deck of cards and I'm trying to select a specific amount cards in pairs randomly from the deck of cards and push them into the gameBoard array but I intitally keep getting duplicate of the pairs. Basically I trying to shuffle cards. I tried using a conditional statement but i dont know if this right way to go about this but it still doesnt work.

javascript

```
const deckOfCards = [
  'card1',
  'card2',
  'card3',
  'card4',
  'card8',
  'card9',
  'card10',
  'card11',
  'card12',
  'card13',
  'card14',
]


let shuffle = deckOfCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * deckOfCards.length)];
let pair = [shuffle, shuffle]
let len = mode

for (let i = pair; i < deckOfCards.length; i++) {
  if (gameBoard.indexOf(deckOfCards[i]) === -1) {
    gameBoard.push(deckOfCards[pair])
  }
}
console.log(gameBoard)
});
let gameBoard = []
```

Comment: So pair will contain a list with 2 same random elements from deckOfCards, right? So what's the purpose of the for loop started with pair? Since pair is an array with 2 elements. Can you clarify what's your expected result?

Comment: I would suggest you use `_.shuffle` from underscore library.

Comment: it's a memory card game so i wanted the pair to run through the loop and output random different pairs without a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

just a thought: you can move the selected element to the back of the array and then randomly select stuff from a slice of the prior, unchanged array... just like `array.slice(0, {a_number_here}`.

something like this I guess (I cannot get your code working so this is not tested yet):

```js
let shuffle = deckOfCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * deckOfCards.length - 5)]
name = deckOfCards.splice(shuffle, 1)
deckOfCards.push(name)
```

by the way if you can use libraries, just go for underscore.js and it would become very simple. just like this:

```js
b = _.shuffle(deckOfCards).slice(0,5);
console.log(b)
```

---

you can also take a look at these repositories too (I haven't yet had the chance to take a look at them though but they kinda have a lot of stars so):

- https://github.com/mmenavas/memory-game/blob/master/js/MemoryGame.js
- https://github.com/code-sketch/memory-game

Comment: yeah. I know but this is for school so only vanilla javascript... but I will try your orginal idea

Comment: ah that is lame... I mean why don't them allow libraries if you are going to use them in future anyway...

Answer (score 0):

you can copy existing one to new one ex : **const cloneSheepsES6 = [...sheeps];**
then you can apply your condition without any duplications

Comment: I will look into this

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an array of unique pair of cards.

```js
const deckOfCards = [
  "card1",
  "card2",
  "card3",
  "card4",
  "card8",
  "card9",
  "card10",
  "card11",
  "card12",
  "card13",
  "card14",
];

const randomArray = [];
let noOfPairs = 6; // No. of pairs required

while (noOfPairs) {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * deckOfCards.length);
  if (randomArray.includes(randomNumber)) {
    continue;
  }
  randomArray.push(randomNumber);
  noOfPairs--;
}

randomArray.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());

const gameBoard = randomArray.map((item) => [
  deckOfCards[item],
  deckOfCards[item],
]);
console.log(gameBoard);
```